# Publishing changes to window with shiny driver

Tags: go, user-interface

I need to show a sequence of `image.RGBA` frames generated by a simulation I'm running, and I'm trying to use [shiny](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/shiny) to do so.
While getting familiar with the package, I tried running a simple example, very similar to one of those [provided](https://github.com/golang/exp/blob/master/shiny/example/basic/main.go), but I do not understand the logic behind [`Window.Publish`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/shiny/screen#Window), and when the changes are shown to the screen.

According to the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/shiny/screen#Uploader) of `Upload` and `Fill`,

> When filling a Window, there will not be any visible effect until
> Publish is called.

However, when I call `w.Publish` after Uploading a buffer or Filling the window, I see only a black window.

Strangely, if I use the same lines to upload or fill the window inside the event loop, the window is updated: I see the background color changing when moving the mouse and the square is drawn when resizing the window, even if I *do not* call `w.Publish` inside the event loop.

```golang
// create a Window
winSize := image.Point{900, 600}
w, err := s.NewWindow(&screen.NewWindowOptions{
    Width:  winSize.X,
    Height: winSize.Y,
    Title:  "Viewer",
})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("s.NewWindow: %+v", err)
}
defer w.Release()

// create a Buffer
size0 := image.Point{30, 30}
b, err := s.NewBuffer(size0)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("s.NewBuffer: %+v", err)
}
defer b.Release()

// fill the buffer with a color
white := color.RGBA{255, 255, 255, 255}
draw.Draw(b.RGBA(), b.RGBA().Bounds(), &image.Uniform{white}, image.Point{0, 0}, draw.Src)

// draw the buffer on the window
w.Upload(image.Point{40, 40}, b, b.Bounds())

// publish the changes
w.Publish()

// at this point I see a black window

var sz size.Event
for {
    e := w.NextEvent()
    switch e := e.(type) {

    default:

    case key.Event:
        if e.Code == key.CodeEscape {
            return
        }

    case mouse.Event:
        // this works, the background changes and the square is drawn
        v := uint8(rand.Intn(255))
        w.Fill(image.Rectangle{image.Point{}, winSize}, color.RGBA{v, v, v, 255}, draw.Src)
        w.Upload(image.Point{30, 30}, b, b.Bounds())

    case size.Event:
        // this works, the background changes and the square is drawn
        sz = e
        w.Fill(sz.Bounds(), color.RGBA{80, 80, 80, 255}, draw.Src)
        w.Upload(image.Point{30, 30}, b, b.Bounds())

    case paint.Event:
        log.Printf("paint.Event: %T %+v", e, e)
    }
}
```

1. Why is the window **not** updated when calling publish?
2. Why **is** the window updated inside the loop, even without calling publish?
3. Why does a `size` event generate a `paint` event? That log line I left is printed after a size event, but not a `mouse` event.

The same thing happens if a use a texture, uploading the buffer to the texture and then copying the texture to the window.

I only need a minimal UI with fast drawing and basic event handling and this package seemed pretty straightforward to use, but if there are other easy options I'm ok with that.

**Edit**:

As I am running this on Ubuntu 20.04 I believe the driver used is X11, so I looked into that implementation of
[Publish](https://github.com/golang/exp/blob/master/shiny/driver/x11driver/window.go#L97) and there is a comment which might explain why the call to publish is not needed to actually draw, but is useful for synchronization:

```golang
func (w *windowImpl) Publish() screen.PublishResult {
    // This sync isn't needed to flush the outgoing X11 requests. Instead, it
    // acts as a form of flow control. Outgoing requests can be quite small on
    // the wire, e.g. draw this texture ID (an integer) to this rectangle (four
    // more integers), but much more expensive on the server (blending a
    // million source and destination pixels). Without this sync, the Go X11
    // client could easily end up sending work at a faster rate than the X11
    // server can serve.
    w.s.xc.Sync()

    return screen.PublishResult{}
}
```

But I still do not understand why drawing outside the loop does not work even with the explicit publish call.

Cheers!